# ASP.NET MVC Pattern - How to use two seperate repositores in a controller(using DI)

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, design-patterns

I have two very simple tables.  Product and ProductCategory (ProductCategory is like a 'lookup' table for Product).  On my controller, for my Index() method I want to list the categories of the products.  When the user clicks on a category, I want to pass my category to my List() method to show all the products of a specific category.

I'm using ninject DI framework; I currently have something like this.

```
private IProductCategory productCategoryRepository;
private IProduct productRepository;

public StoreController(IProductCategory productCategoryRepository)
{
    this.productCategoryRepository = productCategoryRepository;
}

public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View(productCategoryRepository.GetCategories());
}

  public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1) //Use default value
  {
      ...
  };
```

I have basic repositories per table/entity (i.e. GetCategories(), GetProducts(), GetProductsByCategory..etc.) What's the best way...or how can I use two seperate repositories in a controller?  I'd prefer not to pass them both through a controller.

Note:  Product and ProductCategory is not considered an aggregate.

Comment: Consider grouping your repositories into services. Services act on repos that logically work together/have a strong association.

Comment: I'm not familiar with designing 'Services' in the context of MVC applications.  Could you give any links or any info on designing them?  Or maybe you could give a good example of how to implement a service in the example above as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i mentioned earlier, a service layer would help you resolve this. The service layer is a point of contract between the user interface and the middle tier. This could be a WCF service or a simple service implementation i am showing below.

```
public interface IMyProductService 
{
   IList<Product> GetProducts();
   IList<Product> GetProductsByCategory();
   IList<Category> GetCategories();
}

public class MyProductService : IMyProductService
{
   IProductRepository _prodRepo;
   IProductCategoryRepository _catRepo;

   public MyProductService(IProductRepository prodRepo, IProductCategoryRepository catRepo)
   {
      _prodRepo = prodRepo;
      _catRepo = catRepo;
   }

   // The rest of IMyProductService Implementation
}
```

Your MVC controller will have a reference to IMyProductService likely using constructor injection with a DI framework of your choice.